# Adding custom avatar field to comments

Tags: plugin-development, twitter, avatar, gravatar

I want to store a users Twitter Profile Image when I found out that they've tweeted the link of a post (by using the Twitter API), but I'm stuck with the following issue:

How do I store the Profile Image URL?

I figure I must add that to the comments table in the database but then when querying for comments the default Gravatar option would be used. So I think that's not going to work.

So my guess would be: overriding the default avatar function to use the Twitter Profile Image URL if that's present in the database (and how would I add a custom field to the comments database?), or use Gravatar otherwise.

Thanks for helping me out!

Answer (score 0):

There are some plugins that do this functionality of adding the Twitter avatar as the default user Avatar for WordPress,

[Twitter Avatar Reloaded](https://wordpress.org/plugins/twitter-avatar-reloaded/)

[Add Local Avatar](https://wordpress.org/plugins/add-local-avatar/)